# State Restoration emits warning - Causes inexplicable visual abberations

Tags: ios, state-restoration

So far, the internet has no hits for this state restoration warning that's happening to me:

```
-[UIViewController(StateRestoration) decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:]: Warning - State Restoration for UIViewController has presented view controller, but view controller is either not in a window, or the window is hidden. Deferring presentation which might cause flashing when presentation is made after a turn of the run loop:
self: <SomeTabBarController: 0x16e91220>, presented view controller: <UINavigationController: 0x16dbe260>
```

The TabBarController has a view which pushes a ViewController (vc1) onto the navigation controller. VC1 then pushes a NavigationController onto itself modally, which has it's own series of view controllers starting with vc2.

When the state is restored, it flashes back to vc1 (from the snapshot of vc2) before eventually showing vc2 again live.

If anyone has any ideas about where I can even *start* looking into this, that would be a great help.

Comment: I'm also seeing the flashing when restoring a root view controller that is presenting another. I don't get the warning you get, although it seems to describe my issue. Did you find any solution to this yet?

Comment: The warning only happens if you install the .mobileprofile that adds to state restoration debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by making the window key and visible in `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a go, what made you decide to try this?

Comment: The error message you got suggested that the window wasn't fully presented or something, so I wanted to force it. After I tried it, I also saw that Apple is doing the same in this sample project: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StateRestoreChildViews

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. I was looking at that project and missed that bit.